# class is not key value coding-compliant for a nonexistent IBAction

Tags: xcode, nsunknownkeyexception

I have created as swift project in Xcode, and i added Button to the storyboard. The  IBAction of that button is named "WhenButtonPresed", but when I  run the App it gets crashed and i got the below posted error despite i do not have any IBAction called "sd"

**code**:

```
2017-06-19 08:46:21.909 Test_SWIFT_FMDB-1[958:18819] 
<CATransformLayer: 0x7fc353d2e1d0> - changing property 
contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect
2017-06-19 08:46:22.188 Test_SWIFT_FMDB-1[958:18819] *** Terminating 
app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:   
'[<Test_SWIFT_FMDB_1.ViewController 0x7fc353d25fa0> 
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-
compliant for the key sd.'
```

*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Did you control drag from viewController to the button in storyboard?

Comment: right click on your button in storyboard and check if all actions set in a right way. it is possible that something happend there,

Comment: yes, first i named the ban "sd" and when I dragged it to VC file it did not get linked, so i decided to remove the name and then give it a new name which is mentioned in my question, ..at run time i got the error i posted

Comment: I'm sure that you still have the ```sd``` connection on your button. check it again please.

Comment: @user2121 Right click on button and check for how many IBAction is displayed for a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found this error a couple of times and it seems to be a configuration on the UI that is not correct.
It seems to happen when I copy a viewcontroller which has certain links to current objects which I used on the original viewcontroller...

How I correct it:

1. I **select the ViewController** in question

[image]

2. I **check for exclamation marks and remove it**

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check your connections in Interface Builder. You're probably referring to a non-existent `IBOutlet` or `IBAction`.

Also, make sure you don't make double connections in viewcontroller from storyboard from `IBOutlet` or `IBAction`.

Answer (score 0):

It must be something like this in the storyboard.
Just remove the `sd` action. if you only remove it in code, the connection is still alive and it cause a crash in runtime.

In your case: i add the `sd action` and then remove it from code and add another action with another name(press). but as you can see the `sd action` is still exist.

[image]